# Javascript Array - Outputting users input back to them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prompt

Hi I am studying **JavaScript** in college, this is only my first year and we have been asked to do the following question...

•   **Birthdays: The user is invited to enter 12 birthdays, one in each month.  These are written into an array.  The user should then be able to indicate a month and have the birthday for that month returned to them… e.g. if they indicate January, 16th - Aidan is returned as his name and birthday was entered for January.**

We have to prompt the user to enter a friends name and birthday for each month of the year. Then they can enter a month and it will output which friends birthday it is in that month.

We **HAVE** to do this question as an **Array**. I've been able to do it using a really long if/else statement but I don't know where to start with an array.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**If statement I have, I DO NOT have an array code:**

```
function displayDetails() {
  var jan = prompt("Enter a name and date for January");
  var feb = prompt("Enter a name and date for February");
  if (month = "january") {
    alert(jan);
  } else if (month = "february") {
    alert("" + feb);
  }
  // ETC.
}
```

I started off by declaring the array and entering the months.

```
var months = new Array ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct"‌​,"Nov","Dec"];
```

Comment: What code have you tried? We are not a homework service.

Comment: can you post your working code?

Comment: @Ionut I dont have a code, I have no idea where to start sorry.

Comment: post an exemple of array with twelve elements, an exemple of input and the expected output

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't have much code as we don't have any relevant notes on this topic. I started off by declaring the array and entering the months. 
var months = new Array ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

Comment: You said you were able to do it using if statements, like Scott Marcus said this is not a homework service. Depending on you existing code we can point you to a suitable solution

Comment: Then please show what you've done and ask a specific question about where/how you are stuck.

Comment: @Ionut I am aware this isn't a homework service, I have been doing Javascript for 6 weeks. I am just asking for some help.

Comment: @Orly The help will be better and faster the more you provide us with details of the things you tried so far. If you are able to do it with long if/else statement than please show us this code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have an if/else statement that is too long to post.

Comment: @Orly If it is too long show us an excerpt of your code so that we can recognize your solution strategy and how we can improve it.

Comment: @gus27 <script>
            
            
   function displayDetails()
            {
    var jan = prompt("Enter a name and date for January");
    var feb = prompt("Enter a name and date for February");

if(month = "january")
   {
   alert(jan);
   }
    else if(month = "february")
    {
    alert("" + feb);
    }

ETC.

Comment: @Orly Please add this code into your question so other readers don't have to scan all comments to fully understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Consider this answer a warm welcome to stack overflow. Next time, if you want to maximize your chances for an answer, show some research effort. I've **not** written out the full/best answer to your problem, you'll have to read through the answer and combine the info into your own program.*

Cut the problem in to small pieces and find out how to solve these. You've already solved several sub-problems.

> Birthdays: The user is invited to **enter 12 birthdays**, **one in each month**. These are **written into an array**. The user should then be able to **indicate a month** and have the birthday for that month returned to them… e.g. if they indicate January, **16th - Aidan is returned** as his name and birthday was entered for January.

### 1. "Enter ... birthdays"

You've already written this line, so you know how you can have somebody "enter a birthday".

```
var jan = prompt("Enter a name and date for January");
```

### 2. "one in each month"

You've also tried to create an array containing all months. If you check your browser's javascript console, you'll see this resulted in an error:

```
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
var months = new Array ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct"‌​,"Nov","Dec"];
```

This is because you're mixing up two ways to create an array:

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb"];         // Using brackets
var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb") // Using new
```

Once you have your array successfully defined, you can retreive values by writing:

```
var theFirstMonth = months[0];       // Sets theFirstMonth to "Jan"
```

Now, you'll need to know how to "loop" or "iterate" over its values automatically. For example, by using a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop.

```
for (var i = 0;            // Start with a variable `i`, that contains `0`
     i < months.length;    // As long as `i` is smaller then the nr. of months
     i = i + 1) {          // Execute the block below and increase `i` by 1 in the end
  console.log(months[i]);  // Retreive the value from the array using `i`
}
```

You'll see 12 prints in your console, printing each month's name.

### 3. "written into an array"

Instead of retreiving a value from an array, you can also write to it. This is done like any other variable, using `=`:

```
var myArray = ["X", "B", "C"];
myArray[0] = "A"; // myArray is now ["A", "B", "C"]
```

You can also add items to the *end* of the array, by using `push`

```
var myArray = ["A", "B", "C"];
myArray.push("D"); // myArray is now ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Combining the two should look something like this: (I'll let you fill in the empty parts)

```
var months = ["January", "February"];
var birthdays = [];

for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i = i + 1) {
  // Retreive the name of the month, create the question "Enter for ..."
  // ...

  // Ask the user for a date and name, store it in a variable
  // ...

  // push the input to the birthdays array
  // ...
}
```

### 4. "indicate a month, ... is returned"

You know how to get user input, and you know how to retreive a value from the array. There's only one thing left you'll need to do: find the index of a value in an array. Take this array:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March"];
```

The index of "January" is `0`, since it's at the first position. The index of "February" is `1`. Et cetera.

Now, knowing how to iterate through all the values, can you think of a way to find a specific value's index?

```
var valueToSearch = "March";
var months = ["January", "February", "March"];
var valueIndex = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i = i + 1) {
  if (months[i] === valueToSearch) {
    valueIndex = i;
  }
}
```

### Put these things together:

*Input:*

- Create an array with all the months
- Create an empty array for the birthdays
- Loop through each month and ask for user input
- Push the user input to your birthdays array

*Output:*

- Ask the user for the name of a month
- Look up the index of this month in your months array
- Alert the birthday-input from your birthdays array at the index you found

Comment: Shouldn't you use indexOf instead of this loop? (maybe they have not learned about loops yet)

Comment: My line of thought was that it's more useful to try and implement an indexOf manually before using the built in one, so you know what's happening under the hood. Of course, in the end, using Array.prototype.indexOf is the better solution.

Comment: @user3297291 Thank you very much! This has helped me so much!